# Proof that 4-potential exists from Gauss-Faraday field equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

This is a problem concerning covariant formulation of electromagnetism.

Given
$$\partial_{[\alpha} F_{\beta\gamma]}~=~  0 $$
how does one prove that $F$ can be obtained from a 4-potential $A$ such that
$$F_{\alpha \beta}~=~\partial_{\alpha} A_{\beta} - \partial_{\beta} A_{\alpha}~? $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The local existence of a one-form $A$ such that the closed two-form $F$ is exact $F=\mathrm{d}A$ is a consequence of the [Poincare Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms). There might be global obstructions.

Comment: Great answer! Do you know if there is an extension of the Poincare Lemma for the case where the space where $F$ is defined is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? I mean, you may have a non-compact manifold that cannot be embedded. Just curious

Comment: Well, a sufficient condition for the global existence of $A\in\Gamma(T^{*}M)$ on a manifold $M$ is if the second cohomology group $H^2(M)=0$ is trivial, but you probably know that already.